# Better way to refresh page and not scroll to top

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a refresh code that allows me to refresh the page every few seconds, however there are a lot of images that do this flash thing on each couple second reload wondering if there is a better way? This is what I have any help much appreciated! The images only flash if the page is not scrolled to the top??? I don't quite understand, but I have my theory.

Comment: use AJAX for refresh.

Comment: do u need to refresh the whole page or a particular portion of the page

Comment: Don't know how never written ajax before can you show me with the code I have?

Comment: Its a countdown to when a specific test is due. The time comes from a software program database.

Comment: how are u fetching the time...can u post the whole code.AJAX is the solution

Comment: I can't post the whole code can we use email or some other private website?

Comment: not really.That would require money ;) anywaz what back end are u using c#,php,python what??may be i could show you an example which u can follow

Comment: all javascript and css as far as I know, I know hardly anything about this. I started editing this two weeks ago and now I have this problem. Before it was on refresh it would shoot to the top, I fixed that, but once again a new problem.

Comment: can u post the whole code as it is without breaking it up so that i could run it locally and get a feel of the issue.Is it only html , javascript and css.Or if u zip up the files and send me a mail, would be more helful.

Comment: It won't run without the software it pulls the program from. Can I pay you to remote assist and link you to my comp?

Comment: well i can't do that actually now.I'm at my work palce.Any waz zip up the files and send me.Let me have a look.Or if you can tell me how it access data from the software program

Comment: Its a dashboard a visual representation from a piece of software that you input chemical analysis into it spits out results of your "plating bath concentrations" it then tells you to make adds of certain chemicals or when the next test is due...

Comment: Well id be more than willing to compensate for help. I don't know if that's possible, but if it is my email is cwvr6@yahoo.com

Comment: any waz if possible zip up the files and let me have a look if i can help.Or is it access able via public url

Comment: i'll zip the files but they won't be live i'll give you the code then a couple output files and you might be able to see what it looks like how should I send them?

Comment: mail me at italespinner@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to refresh a specific portion of the page every few seconds, you could simply separate the part of the page which you wish to reload into a div, then refresh it like so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#yourdiv").load("yourpage.php #yourdiv");
}, timeout);
```

Where #yourdiv is the name of the div of the site which you want to reload, yourpage.php is the page which you wish to reload it from, and timeout is the amount of time you want it to reload in.  For example, if I wanted to refresh #content every 45 seconds from index.php, I could do this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("#content").load("index.php #content");
}, 45000);
```

This solution uses jQuery, so you'd need to include the jQuery libraries with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before that function.

Comment: Never knew about the [page fragments](http://api.jquery.com/load/) version... not sure why they need to overload all their functions so much.

Comment: jQuery and AJAX are very easy to learn if you know JavaScript. Understand that they aren't separate languages, they're just libraries added onto JavaScript for your use.

Comment: @Mark and OP Css tricks has a nice description of it, if you need more info: http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/

Comment: explain to me yourpage.php my page loads information coming from a software database and a source file... how do I define the php?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: You don't need to use PHP. You can load any page you want -- just replace `yourpage.php` with the name of your "source file" -- it is HTML right?

Comment: @chrisw.iec: Short answer: yes. Long answer: It doesn't matter what the file extension is, as long as the contents of the file have `<html>` in it (or in the case of PHP, generate/output HTML when it's loaded)

Comment: okay i'm going to implement what I think i'm supposed to do in a few hours will you review and tell me what ive done wrong.. i'm sure I wont get it right first try. I have to go visit a customer when I get back i'll do this.

Comment: so if change the script text from javascript and add the src="http... that table goes blabk. Is there a reason by just adding that the content no longer appears? Is there a typo in it or something?

Comment: Make sure you keep `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` exactly how it's written.  That includes the jQuery libraries.  What you want to change is `#content` and `index.php`

Comment: <div id="drawaddrow" align="center">
   <TABLE style="float:center;border:5px; border-style:outset;border-color:#E80000; width:850px; border-spacing:0; border-collapes:collapse;" table border="1">
    script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js">
    DrawAddRow ("","1073741824","Action","Amount","Units","Chemical Additive","Due By","Report ID","","","0","0","Due Status");
    [AddItemsHTML]</script>
   </table>

Comment: That makes the table go blank

Comment: Do I have this written right? I've added the script to the question.